# Variable cannot be resolved error in Java

Tags: java

I know this is a very very common error but I am stuck on this one and I totally don't understand why is it happening.

Here is a part of my code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Manager {
    
    private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    protected static ArrayList<String> identifications = new ArrayList<String>();

    protected static String[] signIn() {
        System.out.println("Hi !");
        System.out.println("Welcome to School Management System");
        System.out.print("Please enter your ID number : ");
        boolean idValid = false;
        String providedID = null;
        int idListPosition = -1;
        do {
            try {
                providedID = sc.nextLine();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Sorry there was an error. Please try again");
                System.out.print("Please enter your ID number : ");
            }
        } while (providedID == null);
        
        while (idValid != true) {
            for (String element : identifications) {
                if (element.equals(providedID)) {
                    idValid = true;
                    idListPosition = identifications.indexOf(element);
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (idValid && idListPosition != -1) {
                System.out.println("Welcome !");
                String[] returnValue = {"true", identifications.get(idListPosition), identifications.get(idListPosition + 1), identifications.get(idListPosition + 2)};
                return (returnValue);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error : the ID you entered does not exist. Please try again");
                providedID = null;
                do {
                    try {
                        providedID = sc.nextLine();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("Sorry there was an error. Please try again");
                        System.out.print("Please enter your ID number : ");
                    }
                } while (providedID == null);
            }

        }
        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        init();
        String[] response = signIn();
        if (response[2].equals("teacher")) {
            Teacher user = new Teacher(response[1], response[2], response[3]);
        }
        if (response[2].equals("student")) {
            Student user = new Student(response[1], response[2], response[3]);
        }

        System.out.println(user);

        while(true) {
            System.out.println("For help type in help");
            System.out.print("Enter a command : ");
            String commandWanted = sc.nextLine();
            
            if (commandWanted.equals("info")) user.showInfos();
        }
    }

    protected static void init() {
        identifications.add("056789");
        identifications.add("teacher");
        identifications.add("Temperson");
    }
}
```

The Teacher and Student classes are empty for now. I just made them use the super constructor of their parent class Person :

```
public class Person {
    String type;
    String name;
    String idNumber;

    public Person(String idnumber, String newType, String providedName) {
        this.idNumber = idnumber;
        this.type = newType;
        this.name = providedName;
    }

    protected String[] showInfos() {
        String[] returnValue = {this.type, this.name, this.idNumber};
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

But I get user cannot be resolved to a variable and user cannot be resolved error.

Normally the code that needs user will never run unless sign in has completed. And since sign in never ends before a correct ID is entered, the user variable will always be assigned to a a value.

Thanks for helping !

Comment: the 3rd and 4rth occurrence of `user` are out of scope; declare `user` at the level of  `String[] response = signIn();`

Comment: But how can I do that since user can be of two different types, depending on the user answer.

Comment: only OP knows, maybe the types share an interface

Answer (score 1):

You're having a Scope problem here:

```
if (response[2].equals("teacher")) {
    Teacher user = new Teacher(response[1], response[2], response[3]);
}
if (response[2].equals("student")) {
    Student user = new Student(response[1], response[2], response[3]);
}

System.out.println(user);
```

Variables declared in a `if` block are local to that `if` block. You can see this in it's simplest form with an example like this:

```
if(true) {
  String value = "Out of Scope";
}
System.out.println(value); //value cannot be seen outside the if block
```

You will need to declare your `Teacher` and/or `Student` variable outside the `if` block if you wish to use them after the block (this is where using your inheritance class would come in handy). Using the previous example:

```
boolean someCondition = true;
String value;
if(someCondition) {
  value = "In Scope - True";
} else {
  value = "In Scope - False";
}
System.out.println(value); //value can now be seen
```

Comment: The `if` doesn't matter; its the *block* that is the issue.

Comment: @ScottHunter I'm using `if` as a short hand identifier of the block since it's the closest identifying element to the block. Using "the block following the if statement" may be a more technically correct description, but didn't really seem worth distinguishing.

Comment: Sure - making it look like this issue is specific to `if` is a good idea.

Comment: Thanks I didn't that in java, variables declared in conditional statements are local to the if block. Then how could I solve my problem ? Because I can't declare user before the if since the ```user``` variable can be of different types depending on user input (teacher or student)

Answer (score 1):

The scope of the user object is limited to the if condition, hence you are getting this error.

If `Teacher` and `Student` extends `Person` then you can try this piece of code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    init();
    String[] response = signIn();
    Person user = null;
    if (response[2].equals("teacher")) {
        user = new Teacher(response[1], response[2], response[3]);
    }
    if (response[2].equals("student")) {
        user = new Student(response[1], response[2], response[3]);
    }

    System.out.println(user);

    while(true) {
        System.out.println("For help type in help");
        System.out.print("Enter a command : ");
        String commandWanted = sc.nextLine();
        
        if (commandWanted.equals("info")) user.showInfos();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am quite new to Java so I have a question. Your code works well ! However, I think declaring ```user``` variable as Person object will prevent me from accessing Student and Teacher methods that are not in the Person class. Am I correct ?

Answer (score 0):

You have declared 2 different versions of `user`, so the `print` statement can't know which you mean.  Or it couldn't if it could see either, but since each is declared inside of its own block, the `print` doesn't see *either* of them.

Comment: I didn't know an if statement in java was considered as a separate scope from its "parent block". Sorry, I come from python world. But then how am I supposed to work around this issue ? Because depending on the user's answer, the variable type of ```user``` can change. How can I fix this ? Thank you for helping ;)

Comment: `if` isn't relevant; its the block (stuff between `{` and `}`) that defines  new scope.